# How to draw quickly lots of filled shapes in LÖVE?

Tags: performance, lua, love2d

I have a platformer game, which is drawn using vector art. That is, I do not use any bitmaps of arbitrary size, but draw everything using `draw.rectangle('fill', ...)` and `draw.polygon('fill', ...)` (mainly for triangles).

However, I have run into performance issues. When I have about 80 blocks, platforms and spikes the framerate drops to 35 FPS, what is rather unpleasant to play. When don't render them, my FPS is about 110.

My blocks generally doesn't move, so I thought about using something like `VertexArray` in SFML, but Love2d hasn't anything like that. I found `love.graphics.SpriteBatch`, but it doesn't seem to support rectangles and triangles without texture.

In summary, how can I quickly draw lots of simple, static shapes in Love2d?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out it is just called [a `Mesh`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Mesh) in Love2d, not vertex array.

Anyway, thanks for all your attention (4 views, that was sarcastic).